# Обучение нейронной сети игре крестики-нолики

Tags: нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект

Пытаюсь сделать простой искусственный интеллект для игры в крестики-нолики. 
Пока архитектура такая: 9 входов, 1 скрытый слой из 9 нейронов, ну и соответственно 9 выходов. Но всё не могу придумать алгоритм обучения: как поощрять и наказывать сеть? Вот сделал ИИ, например, ход на занятую клетку, как скорректировать веса? У кого какие идеи?

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае можно использовать 9 входов-соответственно каждой клетке хода, и достаточно одного выхода-следующий ход.Сеть будет обучаться принимать решения исходя из положения на поле. В случае выигранной партии - всё хорошо, иначе проводим обучение сети-подкручиваем веса. И так пока сеть не обучится до требуемой точности. Можно ввести переменную, в которой будем хранить количество выигранных партий и переменную с количеством сыгранных партий, и проводить обучение, пока точность(отношение значения первой переменной ко второй) не будет удовлетворительным.

Однако для "крестики-нолики" не обязательно использовать нейронную сеть, т.к. множество ходов легко просчитывается простым перебором.

Comment: Но как заставить сеть играть по правилам? Этому же тоже обучить нужно.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, чтобы она ставила крестики(нолики) только в свободных клетках?

Comment: Да, именно это.

Comment: в сеть на каждый вход подаётся информация о том, что находится в клетке(крестик/нолик/пусто)- так сеть получает информацию о положении на игровом поле, допустим, у нас получилось 3 пустых клетки а1,а2,а3. Делаем ход а1, если в итоге сеть проиграла, то обучаем-подкручиваем веса,чтобы сеть выбрала а2, если и в этом случае проиграла-опять обучаем и так далее, пока не будет победа, в этом случае обучение не проводим

Answer (score 1):

Недавно сам пытался сделать нечто подобное, но используя немного другую архитектуру сети:
9 входных нейронов (на них подаем: 0 - если пустая клетка, 1 - если своя клетка, -1 - если клетка занята противником)
Дальше 2 скрытых слоя: 7 нейронов и 5 нейронов
И всего один выходной нейрон

С помощью сети пробегаем каждую свободную клетку и оцениваем, насколько будет удачно сделать сюда свой ход (оценку делает как раз единственный нейрон выходного слоя). Далее выбираем самый удачный вариант и делаем ход.

Нейросеть обучаем генетический алгоритм: создаем поколение (например 64 особи) и заставляем их играть друг с другом попарно, до тех пор, пока не останется одна особь - победитель. Далее формируется новое поколение - родитель сохраняет себя и дает мутировавших потомков. И так до тех пор, пока не получим идеально обученную сеть.